# Sick leave database

Tags: excel

I am new to coding and have taken on this small project and need some help!!    This is the basic set up for the project

Sheet 1

```
Name 1     Name 1        Name 2      Name 3
1/1/2019   2/1/2019      1/1/2019    3/5/2019
1/2/2019   2/2/2019      1/2/2019    3/6/2019
1/3/2019   2/3/2019      1/3/2019    3/7/2019
```

Sheet 2

```
               1/2/2019     1/2/2019       1/3/2019   
Name 1         X                   X
Name 2                             X              X
Name 3         X                   X              X
```

Sorry this basic setup is not showing correctly. I hope this is not to confusing.

The problem I am having is sheet 1 list all the dates the employees enter one years worth and they are in multi columns.  Then sheet 2 is a calendar with a full year list on the top row.  Getting dates in sheet 1 to populate on sheet 2 in the  appropriate  location.   I have tried index match and using if then function with no success.  I could really use some guidance for how to do this project. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you please verify if my edit makes it better while retaining what you mean to say? Also, is the information on Sheet 2 currently correct? Name 1 has 1/3/2019 on sheet 1 but not on sheet 2? And Name 3 on Sheet 2 is showing dates not from Sheet 1?

Comment: Sorry the way the field turned out really does not represent the sheets good enough to give you a  representation of the problem.  I will try and clean up the sheet to help understand better.   Thank for your times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Pivot Tables will work for you.

It will summarize the data of a large dataset into a table with columns and rows representing the data you want to consolidate.

Please take a look at [Create a Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: Thank you very much I will give it a try

Comment: Jerry Yes you edit really helped explain my question in a much more clear way.  Thanks you for you help.